# How could I modfiy this game to where I"m playing agains the computer instead of another user?

Tags: python, random, pygame, dice

I found this code for The Dice Game of Pig, and you input for both players.  I would like to modify it to where player 1 would be a computer and roll automatically.  How would I go about doing this?

```
from random import randint

playercount = 2
maxscore = 100
safescore = [0] * playercount
player = 0
score=0

while max(safescore) < maxscore:
    rolling = input("Player %i: (%i, %i) Rolling? (Y) "
                % (player, safescore[player], score)).strip().lower() in {'yes', 'y', ''}
    if rolling:
        rolled = randint(1, 6)
        print('  Rolled %i' % rolled)
        if rolled == 1:
            print('  Bust! you lose %i but still keep your previous %i'
                  % (score, safescore[player]))
            score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount
        else:
            score += rolled
    else:
        safescore[player] += score
        if safescore[player] >= maxscore:
            break
        print('  Sticking with %i' % safescore[player])
        score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount

print('\nPlayer %i wins with a score of %i' %(player, safescore[player]))
```

Comment: Did you even try? We aren't a code factory here you know :)

Comment: I understand that I'm just looking for some help in the right direction.  I'm pretty new to python.  I tried a few thing, but was getting no where.

Comment: Obviously whenever it's a certain player's turn (`1` for example), the program will have to determine what the player will do instead of asking her -- otherwise it can do just as it does now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from random import randint

playercount = 2
maxscore = 100
safescore = [0] * playercount
player = 0
score=0

while max(safescore) < maxscore:
    if player == 0:
        rolling = 0
        if score < 17 and score + safescore[player] < maxscore:
            rolling = 1
    else:
        rolling = input("Player %i: (%i, %i) Rolling? (Y) "
            % (player, safescore[player], score)).strip().lower() in {'yes', 'y', ''}
    if rolling:
        rolled = randint(1, 6)
        print('  Rolled %i' % rolled)
        if rolled == 1:
            print('  Bust! you lose %i but still keep your previous %i'
                  % (score, safescore[player]))
            score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount
        else:
            score += rolled
    else:
        safescore[player] += score
        if safescore[player] >= maxscore:
            break
        print('  Sticking with %i' % safescore[player])
        score, player = 0, (player + 1) % playercount

print('\nPlayer %i wins with a score of %i' %(player, safescore[player]))
```

Comment: This works only problem is now the game is flawed now because the computer rolls till it bust, so the user will win every time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this "Dice game of Pig" is it something like a black jack?

Comment: pretty much if you go over 21 you bust and don't get any points.

Comment: Not quite understanding this, sometimes I bust at 5, sometimes I bust at 13, sometimes I bust at 20. What is the condition to roll a bust? I've gone as high as 74 to finally bust. Looking at the code, rolling a 1 seems to get you a bust regardless of your total (in black jack, rolling a 1 (ace) is an awesome move).

Comment: It should only bust if you roll 1 or go over 21.  I'm going to test it out a bit more myself I haven't busted at those numbers.

Comment: yeah something from the new code mixed it up because You now bust at random numbers it seems, and I have gone over 21 and not busted.

Comment: I'm sorry I was confused on the rules myself You only bust if you roll a one, someone explained it to me wrong.  You can roll as many times as you want but as soon as you roll a one you bust.

Comment: Yes it works ty :) I do gotta edit the output some like you said, but I should Have it from here.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Check the code again, I updated it to make the AI more intelligent and bust less often and to stop playing as soon as it reaches max score of 100.